# 'wildcard' for all taxonomy terms wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

probably a silly question, but I can't seem to find a 'wildcard' to query all the terms in a custom taxonomy.

here is the query

```
<?php

    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_type' =>'job_listing',
        'orderby'          => 'ASC',

        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_region',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    =>  EVERYTHING,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => EVERYTHING,
            ),
        ),

    ); 

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

?>

What goes in where 'EVERYTHING' is in order to output for all the terms in this taxonomy?

Thanks in advance

NK

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's a little around the houses but I have at least got a working version of what I need.

What I wanted was to dynamically query from two selects (two taxonomies) either a specific term from each (or both) and ANY term from each (or both). That was why I wanted the 'code / value' for something to put in the arguments for ALL terms.

What I did was run four conditional statements around the values given in from the query strings.

if one select == "all" and the other == "all" then we simply don't need to run the taxonomy query because we a querying everything anyway. So when we have just one taxonomy to query and the other is all, we simply miss it out.

This does feel a little junior, but it does work and seems solid so far.

Here is the code (i put the select values into query strings and read them in)

```
<!-- BEFORE WE START WE NEED THE POST ID PASSED IN THE QUERY STRING -->

    <?php $queryStringValueforState = htmlspecialchars($_GET["state"]); ?>
    <?php $queryStringValueforIndustry = htmlspecialchars($_GET["industry"]);   ?>  

    <!-- SEARCH RESULTS -->

    <h2>Results for: <?php echo $queryStringValueforState; ?> <?php echo $queryStringValueforIndustry; ?></h2>

    <?php

    // IF BOTH SELECTS ARE NOT INPUTTED (all)

    if ($queryStringValueforState == "All regions" && $queryStringValueforIndustry == "All industries"){

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' =>'job_listing',
            'orderby' => 'ASC'
        );

    }

    // IF BOTH SELECTS HAVE INPUTTED VALUE

    if ($queryStringValueforState !== "All regions" && $queryStringValueforIndustry !== "All industries"){

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' =>'job_listing',
            'orderby' => 'ASC',

            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_region',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $queryStringValueforState,
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $queryStringValueforIndustry,
                ),
            ),

        );

    }

    // IF REGION SELECT HAS INPUTTED VALUE AND INDUSTRY HAS NOT

    if ($queryStringValueforState !== "All regions" && $queryStringValueforIndustry == "All industries"){

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' =>'job_listing',
            'orderby' => 'ASC',

            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_region',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $queryStringValueforState,
                ),
            ),

        );

    }

    // IF INDUSTRY SELECT HAS INPUTTED VALUE AND REGION HAS NOT

    if ($queryStringValueforState == "All regions" && $queryStringValueforIndustry !== "All industries"){

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' =>'job_listing',
            'orderby' => 'ASC',

            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $queryStringValueforIndustry,
                ),
            ),


        );

    }

    // END CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS AND CONTINUE WITH LOOP

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    ?>

    <div class="single_job_wrapper">
        <div class="job-company-logo"></div>

        <div class="job-content">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_job_description', get_the_content() ); ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my similar issue with a default term value like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
  'tax_query' => [
    [
      'taxonomy' => 'tipos',
      'field' => 'name',
      'terms' => $term ?: ['default_term1', 'default_term2'],
    ]
  ],
]);
```